# Different output in development than on production server?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've got a block of code generating different results on my development machine than on my production server. When I run the SQL that's generated from the named_scope, its identical, and when I run the query directly on identical copies, it gives the correct answer.

Even if I call the method from the console in each env, it gives the same answer.

I only seem to have the problem when I'm calling it from the controller/view. I've got `@end_date = @start_date` to keep consistent formatting with other, similar `named_scopes`.

```
@start_date  = (Time.now)
@end_date    = @start_date
named_scope :today, {:conditions => "shipped_on >= '#{@start_date.year}-#{@start_date.month}-#{@start_date.day} 00:00:00' AND shipped_on <= '#{@end_date.year}-#{@end_date.month}-#{@end_date.day} 23:59:59'"}
```

Any thoughts or places I can check for inconsistencies?

Comment: what differences are you seeing?

Comment: Are the discrepancies caused by the time zone configuration on your servers?  You may need to specify the time zone for your application.

Comment: The difference may be timezone related; after watching over this over the course of a week, its finally dawning on me that the results don't match in the morning, but by afternoon they are accurate.

Comment: The difference is that I won't get the same records; I'm running a query that looks for packages that have a ship_date of today. If I mark a package as shipped on my dev app, it gets picked up by the query. If I do the exact same thing on the production server, same code, I'll mark something as shipped and it won't get picked up by the query. Except maybe it will, many hours later. I'll have to check on that.

Comment: I definitely have a timezone difference somewhere. Does anyone know specific ways to verify time zone settings for a linux/rails/mysql setup?